# Can I filter data in Google Sheets using a condition like not in range?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to use Query Language in Google Sheets, but only select data that is not in a range.

I'm able to do that for a specific field, but I'd like to know how to do for a specific range.

Answer (score 0):

May be we can figure-out what is going wrong with your code, if you provide.

The syntax for filter is

```
FILTER(range, condition1, [condition2, ...])
```

range - The data to be filtered.

condition1 - A column or row containing true or false values corresponding to the first column or row of **range**, or an array formula evaluating to true or false.

condition2 ... - [ OPTIONAL ] - Additional rows or columns containing boolean values TRUE or FALSE indicating whether the corresponding row or column in range should pass through FILTER. Can also contain array formula expressions which evaluate to such rows or columns. All conditions must be of the same type (row or column). Mixing row conditions and column conditions is not permitted.

condition arguments must have exactly the same length as range.

**Sample Usage**

```
FILTER(A2:B26, A2:A26 > 5, D2:D26 < 10)

FILTER(A2:C5, {TRUE; TRUE; FALSE; TRUE})

FILTER(A2:B10, NOT(ISBLANK(A2:A10)))
```

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en

Comment: Thanks. But I was wondering something like to filter values that its not in a certain range. In condition, can I put a range?

Comment: Why not the conditon1 can be true or false, so you have to frame your condition to fit in.